# readResolve() bug?

Tags: java, serialization

The [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) says that ***readResolve works only if all fields are transient***.
Isn't this a bug? Why would the Java creators do a such thing?

**-- update**

Sorry, I mean the [More Effective Java](http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/2008/pdf/TS-6623.pdf), see slide 30.

Comment: I doubt that the book says that, because it's not true. Could you quote from the book, rather than paraphrasing it?

Comment: As we can now see, it doesn't say that. It says 'if you depend on readResolve for instance control, all instance fields with object reference types must be declared transient.' Note the 'if' part ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, slide 29 is:

> ## Item 77: Pop Quiz: Is This Class a Singleton?
>
> ```
> public class Elvis implements Serializable {
>     public static final Elvis INSTANCE = new Elvis();
>     private Elvis() { }
>     private final String[] favoriteSongs =
>         { "Hound Dog", "Heartbreak Hotel" };
>     public void printFavorites() {
>         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(favoriteSongs));
>     }
>     private Object readResolve() {
>         return INSTANCE;
>     }
> }
> ```

slide 30 is:

> ## Answer: Unfortunately Not
>
> ### The first edition oversold the power of readResolve
>
> > Elvis has a nontransient field
>   (favoriteSongs)
>  > Cleverly
>   crafted attack can save reference to
>   deserialized
>      Elvis instance when
>   this field is deserialized
>
> - See ElvisStealer for details (Item 77)
>
> > **readResolve works only if
>   all fields are transient**

Item 77 is:

> ### Item 77: For instance control, prefer enum types to readResolve
>
> ...
>
> If the Elvis class is made to
>   implement Serializable, the following
>   readResolve method suffices to
>   guarantee the singleton property:
>
> ```
> // readResolve for instance control - you can do better!
> private Object readResolve() {
>   // Return the one true Elvis and let the garbage collector
>   // take care of the Elvis impersonator.
>   return INSTANCE;
> }
> ```
>
> This method ignores the deserialized
>   object, returning the distinguished
>   Elvis instance that was created when
>   the class was initialized. Therefore,
>   the serialized form of an Elvis
>   instance need not contain any real
>   data; all instance fields should be
>   declared transient. In fact, **if you
>   depend on readResolve for instance
>   control, all instance fields with
>   object reference types must be
>   declared transient.** Otherwise, it is
>   possible for a determined attacker to
>   secure a reference to the deserialized
>   object before its readResolve method
>   is run, using a technique that is
>   vaguely similar to the MutablePeriod
>   attack in Item 76.
>
> The attack is a bit complicated, but
>   the underlying idea is simple. If a
>   singleton contains a nontransient
>   object reference field, the contents
>   of this field will be deserialized
>   before the singleton’s readResolve
>   method is run. This allows a carefully
>   crafted stream to “steal” a reference
>   to the originally deserialized
>   singleton at the time the contents of
>   the object reference field are
>   deserialized.

It's not a case of only working if all the fields are transient, it's that it's only *safe* if all Object references are transient. The slide you reference goes further and says is *any* fields are non-transient an attacker can grab a reference to the deserialized Object.

As to why: one can argue that Josh Bloch's use of `readResolve()` for a singleton was an unintended use of the API, one the creators didn't envision when they made it. You could also argue it's simply an unforeseen consequence. I don't think however it was a deliberate weakness.

Comment: Yes, this paragraph is better explained, now looks like a programmes bug, not a (ex-)Sun's.

Comment: I think the Slide I'm seeing wrong change "works secure" by "works only if.."

Comment: @cletus: who Josh Block means when he says 'attacker'? I just don't get the case when someone wants/needs to create "second singleton" in my program.

Comment: @Roman: "attacker" here is a bit of a misnomer as it requires code running in the same VM and at the code level there's really no such thing as code security but it matters for things like implementing the subset of Java for the Google App Engine, which is code run inside the VM that can be viewed as "hostile". So if they used `readResolve()` to ensure a singleton on GAE it would be vulnerable to attack.

Comment: It's not really secure if all fields a transient anyway. Avoid singletons. Even avoid making sensitive classes serialisable.

Comment: All this sounds a bit paranoid. As I understand it's enough to avoid one common JVM for me and that bad guy. Until the moment I've succeeded with this more simple task.

Comment: @cletus It's a little more general than that. It's important if the code is ever used in (or inspires code used in) a library available for use where it might be used by mobile code. ("mobile code" - code that is mobile, not (necessarily) code on a phone.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood Josh Bloch. From the java [spec](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/serialization/spec/input.doc6.html):

> For Serializable and Externalizable
>   classes, the readResolve method allows
>   a class to replace/resolve the object
>   read from the stream before it is
>   returned to the caller. By
>   implementing the readResolve method, a
>   class can directly control the types
>   and instances of its own instances
>   being deserialized.

As you can see, here is nothing similar to your statement.

As I know one of the most typical use case for readResolve is when you read serialized singleton (or any object for which you don't want to create a new instance, like manually implemented enumerations i.e. without `enum` keyword). In readResolve you can read fields (if they exist) and decide which of already created objects (singletons as usual) should be returned instead of creating new instance.

Comment: I'd post the wrong link, see my update please.

Comment: @Tom Brito: I saw your update. Cannot comment it, I've never done such tricky things. If you have sources of ElvisStealer class, post them, it's interesting to see.

Comment: No, just the slide before it.

Answer (score 0):

The Singleton behaviour is anyhow violated in the target JVM when using readResolve(), because readResolve() will return the reference to the INSTANCE that was already there in the JVM.

But readObject() will be invoked before the invocation of readResolve() and another object of the Singleton class will be created using reflection by the JVM during deserialization.
Anyway this object may get garbage collected, but temporarily the target JVM has 2 instances of the same type which can be defeating "being Singleton".